# Missing someone (but not romantic)

Tags: usage, meaning-in-context

Say I have a friend that I like a lot and haven't seen in a while.

Is it possible to say "I miss you" **without any risk** of a romantic interpretation?

我想念你 or 我想你 ?

Maybe something more like "I hope we meet again" but still that might be interpreted the wrong way.

Comment: just say 期待能再见面

Answer (score 2):

I would say you should be careful of using 我想念你 or 我想你 , especially to a opposite gender. Usually, we say 我想念你 or 我想你 jokingly to avoid the confusion, except saying it to your 'real honey'.

But if you put 我们都很想（念）你， meaning you are missed among all of our friends, that would get you out of the confusion.

Comment: We met while traveling, but now we are both in other countries.  There is only her and me (via e-mail), so I don't think I can say "我们" or "都"  Maybe some other type of expression?  (I edited the question.)  Or maybe I just shouldn't try to say it; just say "very happy to have met you."

Comment: "very happy to have met you" might be ok 我很高兴认识你 or 很高兴能认识你. I am curious why you just put it in English.

Comment: @WWG, if you know what you miss specifically, for example, you like to talk with her very much, then you could put "和你在一起聊天很开心"（I'm very happy to chat with you. or I enjoy chatting with you.） Or if you like her characteristic, you could put 我觉得你性格很好/很开朗。（I think you have a good personality .） And so on...

Comment: Thanks.  Good idea to be specific (and truthful).  (I use English because I am barely a beginner in Chinese, but I try to get some practice with her and other Chinese folk that I meet.)

Answer (score 1):

Say in a formal speech like 我们后会有期吧 would be much safer. Or just make it explicit as friend: 很高兴认识你这样的朋友。

Answer (score 0):

In Chinese culture people usually don't express their feelings directly unless they really feel they need to. Instead in your situation, people usually start with 好久不见 or 久疏问候 which means "long time no see" to someone they haven't seen for a while.

By saying 我想念你 or 我想你, it is more likely the relationship between two are couples or at least toward to be a couple.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you a very good Mandarin Chinese Learning Twitter.
"Tony Song"
You can ask any questions through it.
And you can learn oral Mandarin Chinese from it.